# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am always getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')
whenever i write the code:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.ticker}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.close}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.date}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.label}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
```

i had used this earlier:

```js
export const iex={
    api_token: 'Bearer token',
    base_url: 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/'
};
```

I cant understand where the problem lies.

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { iex } from '../config/iex.js';

class StockRow extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            date: {},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
    //      query the API
        const url = `${iex.base_url}/stock/${this.props.ticker}/
        intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${iex.api_token}`
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) =>response.json())
        .then((data) =>{
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
                data: data[data.length-1],
            });
        });
    }
render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.ticker}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.close}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.date}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.label}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

export default StockRow;
```

Comment: If that is your real API key, please delete your question and ask it again with the key censored. Check if `this.state.data` actually has data in it before trying to use the data in your render. And importantly, your initial state has a `date`, not a `data`.

Comment: What does `this.state.data` return? Why `data[data.length-1]`? Does actually `console.log(data);` return anything (i.e. the operation is successful)?

Comment: Use ? Operator to check data is defined or not. this.state?.data?.close. Render function will execute once before you get the response

Answer (score 0):

The componentDidMount() method allows us to execute the React code when the component is already placed in the DOM (Document Object Model). This method is called during the Mounting phase of the React Life-cycle i.e after the component is rendered.

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator then you will get the desired output.

```
return (
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.ticker}</td>
            <td>{this.state?.data?.close}</td>
            <td>{this.state?.data?.date}</td>
            <td>{this.state?.data?.label}</td>
        </tr>
    )
```